# Multi employer to employee manage

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, innodb

Hope you are doing good. I am facing issue in multiple employer to employee.

What's going on my mind:

### Employer table

```
employerID,
fname,
lname,
created_at
```

### employee table

```
 employeeID
    fname
    lname
    creted_at
```

This is structure of basic tables then after i created separate table for relation for multi employer to employee.

### employer2employee Table

```
employer_id,
employee_id
```

### salary table

```
salaryID,
salaryAmount,
salaryDate
```

Now i am facing an issue for salary recording. Which ID should be prefer here?
i want to get salary each employee, employer wise. Please help me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't merge the columns in the salary table (salaryID, salaryAmount, salaryDate) within the Employer and Employee tables? This will help you to minimise design complexity, save memory and faster retrieval for data when querying!

Comment: "employee" and "employer" differ by only one letter.  Consider changing one (or both) of the names to make code easier for humans to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this,
Table_Employee :: EmployeeId | FName | LName | CreatedDate | FkSuperEmployeeId

Here FkSuperEmployeeId will get Id of employee from same table

Table_Salary :: SalaryId | SalaryAmount | SalaryDate

Now you can set FkSalaryId in Table_Employee table and if possible then you can set SalaryAmount and SalaryDate in Table_Employee.

So by this way you will be able to handle it easily.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can avoid 3 tables to store employer and employee relationship information.

Instead of 3 tables, use only 1 employee table and have a new column only, which will store the employeeID against the other employee and eployeeID i.e. that particular employeeID in new column is a employer (which is also a employee) of this employee.

***Example -***

[image]

So, Employee 1 doesn't have any employer as Employee_EmployerID is 0. Whereas, Employee 2 has a employer, who is employee 1.

In this case, you can add *employeeID* in your Salary table. And, by doing self join within the employee table, you can fetch out the required information.

**NOTE:** I will suggest to not add *SalaryID* in your Employee table, because employee table is a master table, So having *salaryID* inside the employee table can cost you security issue later if you share the employee table with some outside user.

```
SELECT E1.FName [EmployeeName], E2.FName [EmployerName], S.SalaryAmount
FROM EmployeeTable E1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EmployeeTable E2 ON E1.EmployeeID = E2.Employee_EmployerID
    INNER JOIN SalaryTable S ON S.EmployeeID = E1.EmployeeID
```

However, if you want to keep your structure same as it is with 3 tables for employee-employer relationship, then you can add *SalaryID* into employer2employee table OR add *employeeID* only in your Salary table. :)

In both the case, only joining style with the tables will change while fetch.

Comment: I want to use employee ids for multiple employees, one employee can relate with multiple employee. I think this scenario will not work for this. Field can have only one value and might be it wil not store much amount of ids.